# How can I create a pop-up menu with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, popup

I've been learning to code by my own and I was wondering how can I achieve this kind of stuff, after having clicking a button and then obviously apply the changes the user wants, like this example in eBay:

[image: eBay example]

I know PHP and JavaScript and how Ajax works. You don't need to code it for me but at least give some good approaches.

What is this technically called?
so I can look into it because I can't find anything in Google about 'pop-up menus' so I know that's not how they are called.

Comment: instead of 'pop-up' swap that keyword out for 'modal', 'overlay' or 'lightbox' when searching google.  To get started with a simple modal,  you can create a div with whatever elements you want and hide it initially by giving it display:none; then in jquery, when someone clicks on that button, change display:block; You can then start getting more technical with adding bg-overlay, ajax etc.

Comment: This tutorial is good but uses pure JS https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-your-own-javascript-modal-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery UI's Dialog: https://jqueryui.com/dialog